# Which library is the simpleHTTP function in?

Tags: haskell

I have installed using cabal install network, HTTP, http-conduit, and http-client.  When I run ghc it still throws this error:

```
testRun.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module `Network.HTTP.Simple'
    Perhaps you meant
      Network.HTTP.Base (from HTTP-4000.3.12)
      Network.HTTP.Cookie (from HTTP-4000.3.12)
      Network.HTTP.Stream (from HTTP-4000.3.12)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Network.HTTP.Simple
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or this error if I use Conduit:

```
testRun.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module `Network.HTTP.Conduit'
    Perhaps you meant Network.HTTP.Cookie (from HTTP-4000.3.12)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What do in need to install?

Comment: Are you really using plain GHC or are you building a project with cabal? Double check you've installed http-conduit. Can you also import modules for http-client (`Network.HTTP.Client`)?

Comment: Using hoogle https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.18/hoogle?q=simpleHTTP you can see that `simpleHTTP` comes from the HTTP library, whereas http-conduit exports `simpleHttp`, which has a different case.

Comment: It won't import Network.HTTP.Client either.  I want to use the simpleHttp which conduit exports

Comment: I am using plain ghc.

Comment: Try `ghc -v -package HTTP SOURCE.hs`. Your package paths should be listed.

Comment: Actually, [simpleHttp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.3.2/docs/src/Network.HTTP.Conduit.html#simpleHttp) is defined in Network.HTTP.Conduit. It seems the conduit package has not yet installed properly or GHC cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using a different approach (Stack as a script interpreter), but most likely the following command will run the script with the necessary libraries available:

```
stack --resolver lts-12.9 script testRun.hs
```